# Modification of a row value in pandas python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I have input data in this format:

```py
 {'entities': [('72, 78', '72, 78,Population'), ('56, 68', '56, 68,subtype_1')]}
```

It represents a row value in a csv. I want to transform the value into the following format:

```py
{'entities': [(72, 78,'Population'), (56, 68,'subtype_1')]}
```

Should I parse the csv and transform it using python or is it possible to use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need **json**
write this text in **input.csv**

```
{'entities': [('72, 78', '72, 78,Population'), ('56, 68', '56, 68,subtype_1'), ('72, 78', '72, 78,Population'), ('56, 68', '56, 68,subtype_1')]}
{'entities': [('72, 78', '72, 78,Population'), ('56, 68', '56, 68,subtype_1'), ('72, 78', '72, 78,Population'), ('56, 68', '56, 68,subtype_1')]}
{'entities': [('72, 78', '72, 78,Population'), ('56, 68', '56, 68,subtype_1'), ('72, 78', '72, 78,Population'), ('56, 68', '56, 68,subtype_1')]}
{'entities': [('72, 78', '72, 78,Population'), ('56, 68', '56, 68,subtype_1'), ('72, 78', '72, 78,Population'), ('56, 68', '56, 68,subtype_1')]}
```

and use these codes

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv("input.csv", sep=":")

df.iloc[:,1] = df.iloc[:,1].transform(lambda x: str([tuple(item)[1:] for item in json.loads(x.strip(" }").replace("'","\"").replace("(","[").replace(")","]"))]))

df["merge"] = df.iloc[:,0] + ":" + df.iloc[:,1] + "}"

print(df["merge"])
```